# Heroku login error on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: heroku, ubuntu-16.04, heroku-cli, heroku-api

Unable to login heroku via terminal after recently installing CLI:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
    at new HerokuAPIError (/usr/local/lib/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli/command/lib/api_client.js:12:33)
    at Login.login (/usr/local/lib/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli/command/lib/login.js:78:19)
```

tried moving the `netrc` file, got a message stating it doesn't exist:

```
mv: cannot stat '/home/rodney/.netrc': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

The same mistake occurred to me. The solution I found to be able to login was to write my email in a text file, then copy and paste the moment the email is requested before the error occurs, because in my case the error occurs after running the `heroku login` at the moment when I am typing the email.